# Is there a way in Next.js to modularize a Page Element receiving staticProps via a parsedUrlQuery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Use case is to to open

`http://localhost:3000/users/101`

This is how I would like my page layout to be and Element pull in the second code snippet in **`[id].tsx`**

```
import CTASection from '../../components/samples/CTASection';
import { User } from "../../interfaces";
import { GetStaticProps, GetStaticPaths } from "next";
import Element from "pages/users/element";

const Element = ({ item, errors }: Props) => {
  return (
     <Box>
        <Element />
        <CTASection />
      </Box>
  )
}

export default Id;


export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on users
  const paths = sampleUserData.map((user) => ({
    params: { id: user.id.toString() },
  }));
  
  return { paths, fallback: false };
};


export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  try {
    const id = params?.id;
    const item = sampleUserData.find((data) => data.id === Number(id));
    return { props: { item } };
  } catch (error) {
    return { props: { errors: 'ERROR Loading Data' } };
  }
};
```

However it only renders the query parameters if I insert my **`element.tsx`** page in a non-modular fashion like this:

```
...
  return (
     <Box>

        <Grid gap={2}>
          <Heading as="h2" fontSize={{ base: "lg", sm: "3xl" }}>
            Verifikation
          </Heading>

          <Box
            backgroundColor={colorMode === "light" ? "gray.200" : "gray.500"}
            padding={4}
            borderRadius={4}
          >
            <Box fontSize={textSize} title={`${
              item ? item.name : "User Detail"
            }`}>

              {item && <ListDetail item={item} />}

            </Box>

          </Box>
        </Grid>

        <CTASection />
      </Box>
  )
...
```

This is the ListDetail.tsx:

```
    import * as React from "react";

    import { User } from "../../interfaces";

    type ListDetailProps = {
      item: User;
    };

    const ListDetail = ({ item: user }: ListDetailProps) => (
      <div>
        <h1>User: {user.name}</h1>
        <p>ID: {user.id}</p>
      </div>
    );

    export default ListDetail;
```

Comment: _"it only renders the query parameters if I insert my `element.tsx` page in a non-modular fashion"_ - I'm not sure I follow. What is the actual issue? What's stopping you from using the layout in the first code block?

Answer (score 1):

you can use gerServerSideProps

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res, query, params }) => {
    // your code...
    // you have access to req, res, query, params, headers, cookies, and many more.

    return {
        props: {}
    }
}
```